# Excel formula: check if ranges in two worksheets contain anything else other than specific values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula in one cell in Sheet A to check whether cell range A1:C10 in Sheet B and cell range A1:C10 in Sheet C contains anything else apart from blank cells and words ‘Y’ ‘Good’, ‘N/A’. If this formula is true return word “Contains”, if not true, return word “Does not contain”.

Thank you for your help all!

I have been unsuccessful in getting this to work.

Answer (score 2):

### Indicate Whether Tow Ranges Do Not Contain Given Values (Strings)

[image]

```
=LET(Data1,'B'!A1:C10,Data2,'C'!A1:C10,
        Criteria,{"Y";"Good";"N/A"},
        y,"Contains",n,"Does not contain",
    d,UNIQUE(TOCOL(VSTACK(Data1,Data2),1)),
    m,XMATCH(FILTER(d,d<>""),Criteria),
IFERROR(IF((COUNT(m))<ROWS(m),y,n),y))
```

- The 2nd parameter of `TOCOL` is set to `1` to remove blanks. The expression `FILTER(d,d<>"")` is used to remove the nothings. Read the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-if-to-check-if-a-cell-is-blank-dff4eda1-6187-4b83-b7f6-4c3c0a1e2188) to understand what is what: `Blank` vs `Nothing` (I call them `Empty` vs `Blank` respectively (in VBA)).
- `IFERROR` will cover for error values resulting in *y* i.e. `Contains`.
- To use a single expression, e.g. `Data,'B:C'!A1:C10,` requires the sheets to be consecutive and in this order so I'm not using it.
- On my end, Excel is removing the single quotes from `B` but doesn't allow removing them from `C`. Not sure what that's all about. I'm leaving them for both sheets.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
=IF(OR(ISNA(XMATCH(VSTACK(B!A1:C10&"",'C'!A1:C10&""),{"","Y","Good","N/A"}))),"Contains","Does not contain")
```

Answer (score 1):

Formula, you are looking for might look like this for example:

=**IF**(**COUNTIFS**(B!A1:C10;"<>"&"Y";B!A1:C10;"<>"&"";B!A1:C10;"<>"&"Good";B!A1:C10;"<>" & "N/A") **+** **COUNTIFS**('C'!A1:C10;"<>"&"Y";'C'!A1:C10;"<>"&"";'C'!A1:C10;"<>"&"Good";'C'!A1:C10;"<>" & "N/A") **>  0**;"**Contains**";"**Does not contain**")

It consists of one IF statement and two COUNTIFS statements.
COUNTIFS simply count cells wich meet your conditions within given range. Then, if summ of their results is more then zero the answer is "Contains". If summ equals zero the answer is "Does not contain".

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you! Some of the cells actually contain a formula and are not blank and your formula would work if there would not be any formulas in the range of cells. Do you know a workaround for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be:

```
=IF(
    AND(
        MMULT(--(TOCOL('Sheet A:Sheet B'!A1:C10,1)={"Y","Good","N/A"}),
              SEQUENCE(3,,,0))
        ),
    "Contains",
    "Does not contain")
```

Comment: `TOCOL()` will return 0 for empty cells though if you use it like that. Meaning, you can't distinguish between empty cells or actual zero's nomore.

Comment: My perception is that empty is different than `{"Y","Good","N/A"}` (just like `0`).
If blanks are allowed this should've been mentioned in the question, if you ask me.

Comment: Regardless I think your solution using MATCH is more efficient, because it will stop checking after the first match, while MMULT would check the whole range. Upvoted from my side :)

Comment: No worries, and thanks. BTW, blank cells *are* mentioned in OP.

Comment: Oops, overread that. Fixed it by adding condition `1` to TOCOL (ignore blanks). This would not work for cells within the range that would contain a formula returning empty string, instead of true blanks.